# Parameter error, but still seems to work?

Tags: vb.net, image, oracle

I'm pulling a BLOB from oracle.  I've done this througout the app without issue.  However on this call I'm getting an error.  Yet the funny thing is once I close the error the image loads just fine.

```
        Dim Conn As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(Private)
        Conn.Open()
        Dim mySelectQuery As String = "Select IMAGE,IMAGE_NAME,SIZE_BYTES from MPCS.IMAGE_RESOURCE WHERE IR_ID ='" & irid & "'"
        Dim CMD As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(mySelectQuery, Conn)
        Dim Myreader As OleDbDataReader
        Myreader = CMD.ExecuteReader()
        Myreader.Read()

        Dim Allbytes As Byte() = Myreader("IMAGE")

        Using memory As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream(Allbytes)
            Dim newimage = New Bitmap(memory)
            PictureBox1.Image = newimage
        End Using
```

Stranger enough, it doesn't happen on other items I choose to pull the image for.  I've ran through each one debugging line by line comparing one that errors and one that doesn't, and each line of has correct data.

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ileL.png)

Comment: Use parameters to solve your problem.  ID probably isn't a string, is it?

Comment: IR_ID is a string.  And again, it works without error sometimes that's why I'm confused.  I can't find anything different with the ones that work and the ones that don't.

Comment: What is the error/exception message?

Comment: `ex = {"Parameter is not valid."}` And then once I click ok the image continues to display as it should, as the ones that don't give this error do.

Comment: What is the value of Myreader("IMAGE") when it errors out?  Sounds like you don't have valid bytes or an invalid image.

Comment: The bytes are present.  I stepped through each line making sure.  And then again once I close out the error, and let the process continue to run the image appears in the picture box.

Comment: You are basically arguing with us that everything is working.  Which line throws the error?

Comment: `Myreader("IMAGE")` returns `Object`, you might try using the `DataReader.GetBytes()` function or explicitly convert it.  *Maybe* use `Image.FromStream` and definitely start disposing things.

Comment: Try `memory.Position = 0` before `Dim newimage = New Bitmap(memory)`.